# why does visual studio always uninstall sharepoint provider hosted app?

Tags: sharepoint-2013

Every time I run my SharePoint provider hosted app, it uninstalls the app before reinstalling. I have not changed the sharepoint settings so just want to run the website. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio will uninstall the add-in and re-install the add-in when you press F5 in the following cases:

- You have changed something in the add-in manifest file or the add-in project
- You have enabled App Installed event receivers

If you just want to run the website, then disable add-in event receivers while debugging.